# Is there any way to merge and remove duplicate test case from cucmber jvm report?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm

I have two runners in my automation project as follows:

Main runner - Executes all the @ui-test tagged test cases and if a scenario is failed target/rerun.txt will be populated with the scenario location (e.g. features/Dummy.feature:22):

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "classpath:features",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber.json", "rerun:target/rerun.txt"},
    tags = {"@ui-test", "~@ignore"}
)
```

Secondary runner - Re-executes the scenarios from target/rerun.txt:

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "@target/rerun.txt",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report-rerun", "json:target/cucumber_rerun.json"}
)
```

When the execution is performed two result json files are created:

cucumber.json
cucumber_rerun.json

Maven Cucumber Reporting plugin will collect the results and will create a combined report.

The problem is, even if all the target/rerun.txt tests are passed in the second run, the report status will remain failed because of the cucumber.json.

Is there a way (to set up Cucumber-JVM Reports plugin or modify the upper presented runners) to overwrite cucumber.json with the results from cucumber_rerun.json and to publish only the modified cucumber.json?

Answer (score 0):

```
As given in link-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742420/combine-multiple-json-results-in-one-updated-cucumber-jvm-report?rq=1

I wrote the logic to perform following steps in second runner-

1- Deserialize the cucumber.json data into POJO.
2- Remove the testcases data which got failed from POJO as these cases will be rerun.
3- Serialize the POJO objects into json and overwrite the cucumber.json file

Below is the logic for same-
@BeforeClass
public static void readjson() {
try{

File jsonFile = new File("./target/cucumber.json");
String cucumberJsondata=new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jsonFile.toURI())));
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
          //Root is the POJO Class 
          List<Root> listRoot = om.readValue(cucumberJsondata, new TypeReference<List<Root>>(){});
          //Root root = om.readValue(cucumberJsondata, Root.class);
          boolean removeflag=false;
          
          int[][]FeatureScn = new int[listRoot.size()][];
          //ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> FeatureScn = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
          int featurecount=0;
          for(Root root:listRoot)
          {       
                  List<Element> ele=root.elements;
                  int scncount=0;
                  ArrayList<Integer> removeEleIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                  FeatureScn[featurecount] = new int[root.elements.size()];
                  for(Element e:root.elements)//scenario counter
                  {
                      if(e.type.equalsIgnoreCase("scenario"))
                      {   
                          removeflag=false;
                          for(Step s:e.steps)
                          {
                              if(s.result.status.equals("failed"))
                              {
                                  removeflag=true;
                                  break;
                              }
                              
                          }
                         
                          if(removeflag)
                                 FeatureScn[featurecount][scncount]= scncount;   
                          else
                              FeatureScn[featurecount][scncount]= -1;  
                      }    
                      
                      scncount++;
                  }
                  featurecount++;
                  
          }
          for(int i =0;i<listRoot.size();i++)
          {
              for(int j=0;j<FeatureScn[i].length;j++)
                  if(FeatureScn[i][j]!=-1)
                      listRoot.get(i).getElements().remove(FeatureScn[i][j]);
          }
          ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
          FileOutputStream fos = null;
          File file = new File("target/cucumber.json");
            if (file.exists()) {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
                objectMapper.writeValue(fos, listRoot);
                fos.close();
            }

          
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     System.out.println("An error occurred.");
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Juhi, Could you please add the import statements and dependencies required for this implementation?